# Calling Services from another server and using them through AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, service

This is my code in javascript

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("www.test.com/my_project/learningresources/ajaxvalue")
    .success(function (response) {$scope.names = response;});
});`
```

I am calling a service that is written in spring and is present on a differnt server. This service returns a json array. In html I am using the following code to show the result returned by this service:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
</tr>
```

I get the following javascript bug "XMLHttpRequest cannot load www.test.com/my_project/learningresources/ajaxvalue. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://current_site.com' is therefore not allowed access."

Is this due to some database permissions. i am not able to get this. I am new in AngularJS and Spring.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en-US

Comment: post the json data also.

Comment: [{"name":"Arrange seminar for Android","resourceType":"SEMIN"},{"name":"Arrange seminar for SalesForce","resourceType":"SEMIN"},{"name":"Big Data Trainig--Test","resourceType":"TRAIN"},{"name":"JAVA- Training","resourceType":"TRAIN"},{"name":"SAP- Training","resourceType":"TRAIN"}]

Answer (score 0):

This is because of cross domain requests, by default requests to a different domain will not be allowed.

The 2 main solutions are:

- CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing): The server needs to add a response header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and add your domain to this header. You need access to the server code for this. Something along the lines of `response.addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'domain.foo.bar/*');` --> This depends on the server language off course.
- Another solution is to use JSONP.

Read more about CORS [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (JSONP link at the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do a cross domain request, that is not permitted via browser.
solutions can be:

1.call your server service that acts as a bridge with external domain and return back data to your angular function.

2.Use a jsonp proxy call it and declare your callback function inside parameters (there is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21217227/getting-results-from-api/29031811#29031811) with jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Close the chrome browser
Press win+r. 
copy paste the following

chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security

Then try to view the result and then tell whether you get the same error after loading the app.
Good luck.

Comment: did you close the chrome completely?

Comment: This only fixes it for the Chrome browser + it's not really an option to let every client fix this in their browser settings

Comment: Yes.It should be allowed from backend.